# How to persuade the React/MUI Theme Engine to namespace all MUI CSS rules?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, themes

We've got a problem with React Apps, imported as microfrontends. A Landingpage (written in React/MUI) imports a number of Apps (written in React/MUI v4 or v5, also need to be able to run standalone, therefore they have their own themes). The problem arises that those Apps all do create their own theme and set different base rules on the Mui CSS classes (e.g. `.MuiGrid-container`). Switching between Apps in the Landingpage then seems to work the following way:

- Landingpage loads its theme.
- App 1 is loaded and loads its theme.
- App 2 is loaded and loads its own theme, overriding some rules from App 1. Not a problem, because App 1 is not visible.
- App 1 is loaded again and loads its theme ... but replaces its old theme, so the theme of App 2 is now later in the CSS rules and therefore overrides the rules from App 1.

We only have control over our own App, not over the Landingpage; and it is App 2 that is leaking into our App 1.

The obvious solution would be to namespace our theme, i.e. inserting a prefix class to each and every CSS rule emitted by our App to increase specificity and not leak into other Apps. We expected that there'd be an option to `createTheme` or `<ThemeProvider>` or something like that, but the docs did not turn up anything.

So the question now is: How do we namespace our React/MUI v5 Theme?

To be exact, our idea is that a theme that is created with:

```
createTheme(
  {
    palette: palette,
    components: {
      MuiGrid: {
        styleOverrides: {
          container: {
            flexWrap: "nowrap",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
)
```

and included in the App using `<ThemeProvider theme={resultOfCreateTheme}>` should produce a CSS rule like

```
.ourNamespaceElementClassName .MuiGrid-container {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Currently, it always produces

```
.MuiGrid-container {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

and multiple Apps doing this may leak into each other.

Any hints about alternative approaches are also welcome, as we might've run into a XY problem here. We just don't have control over the Landingpage nor Apps 2..n, so we need to somehow "theme-proof" our own App 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now did find a solution to our problem. Its slightly different to our first idea outlined in the question.

This solution puts a namespace/scope on all MUI CSS classes. Per default, all MUI elements have classes like:

```
<div class="MuiGrid-container"></div>
```

Now we're configuring the `ClassNameGenerator` class (in index.tsx) and override the class name generation function:

```
import { unstable_ClassNameGenerator as ClassNameGenerator } from '@mui/material/className';

ClassNameGenerator.configure((componentName) => `namespaceXYZ-${componentName}`);
```

With that, all our elements and MUI CSS classes now have a namespace prefix:

```
<div class="namespaceXYZ-MuiGrid-container"></div>
```

One caveat: MUI "marker classes" (like `Mui-disabled` et al) do not get the prefix. But since those are styled only in conjunction with the components CSS classes, it is not a problem. It only has to be heeded when writing custom CSS with more than one class in the selector.

Answer (score -1):

First you should create default Theme and write your style in this file, for example like cod of below.

```js
const defaultTheme = {
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: ...,
            light:...,
            dark:...,
        },
        secondary: {
           ...
        },
        warning: {
           ...
        },
        success: {
            ...
        },
        info: {
           ...
        },
          text: {
           ...
        },
          background: {
            ...
        },
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiBackdrop: {
          root: {
            ...
          },
        },
        MuiMenu: {
          paper: {
            ...
          },
        },
        MuiSelect: {
          icon: {
            color: "#B9B9B9",
          },
        },
        MuiListItem: {
            root: {
              "&$selected": {
                ...,
                "&:focus": {
                  backgroundColor: "#F3F5FF",
                },
              },
            },
            button: {
              "&:hover, &:focus": {
                backgroundColor: "#F3F5FF",
              },
            },
        },`enter code here`
            head: {
              ...,
            },
            body: {
             ...,
            },
        },
        PrivateSwitchBase: {
            root: {
              ...
            }
        }
    }, 
     
};
```

in ... you put your style like background and another style.
then you add

```js
const themes = {
      default: createTheme({...defaultTheme}),
  };
```

then in index.js add

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={Themes.default}>
    <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: As I suggested in the question, that is the way we already do it. And that is how all other Apps in that Landingpage probably do it. The problem is that the MUI CSS classes produced by the various apps imported in the Landingpage override each other according to the loading order -- which is determined by the user requesting the different apps, therefore wehave to assume it to be random. Sorry, but I don't see how this answers my question.